# Android studio stuck on Installing Apk

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android studio when i am trying to install an apk studio keeps on telling apk is installing but after taking sometime its keep on installing. It is neither installing nor showing any error.It neither install apk on virtual as well as physical device.My Android studio is of 2.3.3.

I have ram of 8GB

Comment: Please provide more information, as much as possible.

Comment: I might be able to give an answer, buy I will need a little bit more info. How large is the APK of your app? Can you give me a specific time its taking? Doesnt need to be exact, just an idea.

Comment: It just almost 4-5 MB apk generated by Android studio and after waiting for almost 15-20 minutes Android studio showing installing apk but not install in physical as well as virtual phone...?????   What to do now any idea????

Comment: It was working for me literally just 5 minutes ago and now its decided itl just hang for the sake of it. What the hell could possibly change in 5 minutes on a device that would prevent the installation of apps?

Comment: This happens to me 3-4 times a week :( I've tried resetting all settings, clearing caches, and even went as far as deleting all android studio/gradle folders and reinstalling android studio. Are you working with a real phone or emulator?

Comment: It's probably a problem with your device. Check out this question.        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221903/android-studio-stuck-on-installing-apk

Answer (score 0):

I was using Android Studio 3.1 and had encountered the same issue. I tried every solution I can find on StackOverFlow but has no luck. Finally, I solved it by updating Android Studio to 3.1.1

Try to update your Android Studio version first before you re-installing everything. It might save a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score -1):

**Solved!**

The problem is solved by just deleting whole android studio from my pc(Its includes all old settings of android) and reinstall android studio.

Now, android studio works perfectly in my system.