# Flutter fresh installation flutter run stuck

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter i have fresh installtion.

All as in docs.

As after fresh installation i was fine worked but when i want to work on another day flutter run i stuck.... I do not know why. I only make boilerplate app. I xcode when i build app is opening in simulator but stating as flutter run not working. I even try to wait 20 min with this flutter run but still stuck

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.6.4-pre.14, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale
    pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 1.6.4-pre.14 at /Users/db/Desktop/Mobile/flutter
    • Framework revision 81c38b22cb (32 hours ago), 2019-05-24 22:51:02 -0400
    • Engine revision 8dc3a4cde2
    • Dart version 2.3.2 (build 2.3.2-dev.0.0 e3edfd36b2)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/db/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.0

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 35.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 8 • F35EFD3E-C637-427A-8405-30EDF202939A • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

flutter run -v stuck at this stage.

```
+file:///Users/db/Desktop/Mobile/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/widgets.d
art
[        ] -> +file:///Users/db/Desktop/Flutter/iamsmart/lib/main.dart
[        ] -> 35191e22-84d6-4fab-abef-178ae9e4c665 build/app.dill 0
[ +319 ms] Building bundle
[        ] Writing asset files to build/flutter_assets
[  +55 ms] Wrote build/flutter_assets
[  +12 ms] Using legacy Xcode build system.
[  +27 ms] executing: [/Users/db/Desktop/Flutter/iamsmart/ios/]
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
```

Comment: Can you confirm if you still encounter this? This might be similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35988.

Comment: check here for installations of flutter broh https://www.flutterondart.com/2019/09/installation-of-flutter-dart.html

Comment: can you share your pubspec.yaml file. Do you have a cloud firebase dependency?

Comment: hey guys i tried everytimg i think only what's let is wipe out my mac and make fresh installation

Comment: This is my solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353663/6760642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to 1.9.1-hotfix4 fixed the problem

Answer (score 5):

Run this command

```
flutter clean
```

And then again

```
flutter run
```

Comment: Hey I have upgraded to 1.7.8 and still have the same issue that flutter run takes sooo long to run on iOS simulator. But when i am flutter run on windows or mac android it is okey

Comment: Try to open your project in Xcode. You can do this by navigating to Project Folder > iOS> runner.xcworkspace. Now build your project and check if it gives an error

Comment: Now run the app in any simulator using Xcode. If everything goes well then try to use VSCode, it should complete without any errors

Comment: yeah i know that i can compile/buold app in xocde and runit on simulator but how to refresh/reload that simulator? as app started in xcode not in VScode with flutter run so 'r' will not work

Comment: Ensure that you have selected a team and checked on "Automatically manage signing", Also try to generate a new certificate. After that open VSCode and run your code

Comment: You forgot flutter pub get step

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to upgrade your flutter version to v 1.7.8 by running **this
   command this needs internet connection**

```
    flutter upgrade
```

2. Try this command

```
    flutter clean
```

3. Change your flutter channel to stable

```
    flutter channel stable
```

4. Check your internet connection because sometimes it prevents me from
   running my app

Comment: looks like maybe it fixed it but i will make more builds. and flutter runs to check, thanks

Comment: you should upvote my answer not to say thanks XD,wish you all the best

Comment: i am not saying it works...i know to upvote i need to tested more one or two builds are not proving anything....

Comment: Hey I have upgraded to 1.7.8 and still have the same issue that flutter run takes sooo long to run on iOS simulator. But when i am flutter run on windows or mac android it is okey

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch your flutter channel **master** to **stable** channel. After switching the channels you should call `flutter upgrade` to download the Flutter SDK and dependent packages.

Do this steps in the terminal

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade
```

try to run your code after this steps.

Comment: Hey I have upgraded to 1.7.8 and still have the same issue that flutter run takes sooo long to run on iOS simulator. But when i am flutter run on windows or mac android it is okey

Comment: Is your provided information, in your question, the same ? Like error or ```flutter doctor -v``` information? If not, can you update your question pls.

Answer (score 0):

Your flutter doctor isn't showing any error as you had shared the commands.I think to share the run command terminal so that we can find out the stack of flowing of commands.
If you are getting error to build flutter project then you should update the Android Studio or VS Code Editor.
You can refer here:
Android studio-https://developer.android.com/studio
VS Code-https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

If you are able to create flutter project but doesn't getting run command then you need to update flutter and dart.
You can refer here:
Flutter-https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases
Dart-https://dart.dev/get-dart

If still you are suffering from error then you need to share some more Pics.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something's gone wrong after you changed some files in of flutter ide. Also it does after updates crashed.
So the thing you should do is firstly backup your projects if it indeed. After backup remove the ide and be sure uninstalling complate succesful. Restart your computer and install all decencies again. Because sometimes upgrading does not works well to get good result.

P.S : Dont forget using flutter doctor for checking if any problem comes out.