# Endless install in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

In the recent times I am considering to change my work title from "Android Developer" to "Endless install progress watcher".

It has been happening ever more often that when I try to run my applications or tests Android Studio stucks in endless installing progress like the image below:

[image]

This progress remains like forever. It used to be that if I disconnect my device and connect again the next attempt will succeed. Now it is often the case that I need multiple re-connects until I am able to run.

The speculation is the problem is due to ADB hanging and loosing connection somehow, but I do not know how to overcome that.

My configuration is:
 - Ubuntu Linux, but colleagues experience the same on Mac OS e.g.
 - Android Studio 3.5
 - device is Nexus 5X, but the same happens on many other devices

Comment: I think you should have a look at this topic right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221903/android-studio-stuck-on-installing-apk

Comment: Run Android studio from terminal and watch the logs after you run your task again. If it prints anything paste it here.

Comment: this is an error description alike "it's not working" and this not even limited to one device.

Comment: Is there same problem with relese APK file?

Comment: @Kaushik Burkule i do not know, but i definitely do need debug working too. Will the results of this experiment help in determining the cause?

Comment: Have you tried the all solution from first link?

Comment: @Kaushik Burkule not all yet. I am applying one after another in order to see which one, if any affects the result. Probably it will take me another couple of days to finalize the experiments

Comment: What is your system configuration? A system running low on RAM will have issues running Android Studio. I would recommend at least 12 GB of RAM.

Comment: 32 GB RAM with 4 (8 virtual) cpu i7. My RAM is far from exhausted

Comment: @BorisStrandjev, did you try Wi-Fi debugging?

Comment: Check another USB port  in Your workstation and/or USB cable used to connect device, maybe its hardware problem

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Is your app is installed before on device, Btw Great to know that you are organizing GDG Sofia, I was also organizer GDG Rajkot.

Comment: @PratikButani I have it installed yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try if any of this this solves your problem:

1. Clean project
2. Use another device
3. Go to developer options -> Select debug app -> Turn on "wait for debugger" -> Run your app again
4. In Developer Options turn off "Monitor apps installed by ADB".
5. Reboot your phone
6. Reinstall Android studio

Answer (score 1):

You may need to try: File -> Settings (Android Studio -> preferences for mac) -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run and turn it off.

Comment: Are you using latest Android  Studio. I do not seem to be able to find this option

Comment: It changed! ok just look it up in your settings if that does not work look at this driver list [https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers](here)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I solved it by revoking USB Debugging Authorizations and then re-enabling USB Debugging on my chosen device(s).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem wasn't with Android Studio, but with the device you're using for testing. I tried a different device and it behaved normally, progressing beyond "Installing APK" and stopping on breakpoints.

Somehow the **"wait for debugger"** setting in developer options on the problem device had switched to off. I switched this back on and now this device is behaving normally.

Comment: I am not sure where this setting is

Comment: if you're using Mobile phone for testing than you can find this  in your mobile setting > developer mode>Wait for debugger

Answer (score 1):

You must try:

- Latest Android Emulator Download or Update : Android Emulator **version 29.2.1**
- Delete all Emulator which is created previously and Create New for Android 9 or 10.
- Uninstall app from device if already installed previously. [(Remove for all users.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27456355/1318946)

I think 3rd point will work because you have Nexus Device, Must visit above link.

Hope you will get resolve your issue. Thank you.

Comment: I am using real device. I confirm fresh install never exhibits the problem, but my problem is that sometimes I need to preserve the installation in between runs, thus I can not afford always uninstalling

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen sometimes if you have multiple user accounts on your device. If you uninstall it from the device, it might still be installed for other users and therefore Android Studio can't install the new APK.

Try to do the following (even if the app is not visible on your device!):

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

If you have seen a success message, that means the app was successfully uninstalled and Android Studio should be able to install the app properly now.

Comment: I do not have multiple users on my device

Comment: Have you tried it, though? When it happened to me, I had a second user account without me knowing.

Comment: Yup, I checked in the accounts menu