# Flutter run stuck at "Installing build\...\app.apk" if run by VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, apk

I'm trying to run a Flutter app on a physical Android device using Visual Studio Code with the [Dart Code/Flutter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter) (which used to work).

**But when I try to start the app, it is stuck at `Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...` and a white screen appears on my phone.**

I know that there are already a number of threads on this topic<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221903/android-studio-stuck-on-installing-apk) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394504/flutter-stuck-at-installing-build-app-outputs-apk-app-apk) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701359/flutter-run-stuck-at-installing-build-app-outputs-apk-app-apk)</sup>, but the suggested solutions did not work for me, including:

- Rebooting my phone and my computer
- Uninstalling the app
- `flutter clean`
- Building the app using `flutter build`, manually installing the `app-debug.apk`* and then starting the app from VS Code again
- Uninstalling the app using `adb uninstall` and installing `app.apk` using `adb install`
- Clearing cache and storing from the app settings before uninstalling
- Revoking USB debugging authorizations
- Disabling *Play Protect* on my phone
- Increasing the Logger Buffer Size in my phone's developer options

*after installing the APK file myself, the app worked, but of course I had no debugging capabilities

---

When I execute `flutter run` in the terminal, the app opens on my phone and works fine. However hot reload does not work and only the following is printed out:

```
$ flutter run -d FA685YJ01209
Launching lib/main.dart on HTC One M9 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         4.0s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
```

It is not possible to attach to that process from Visual Studio Code either.

---

I also tried to start the app on an emulator using Visual Studio Code. In that case, it gets stuck at `Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...`.

---

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at /opt/flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (7 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/scriptim/Dev/Android/SDK/
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • HTC One M9 • FA685YJ01209 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there were changes on the [stable branch](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/stable) that solved the problem. After a `git pull` everything works fine. Unfortunately I can't figure out where exactly the problem was.